# Flutter display nested json in ListView return type String is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast flutter

Tags: flutter, api, rest, dart

JSON RESPONSE
{
"data": {
"Address": "xyz",
"CityID": "1",
"CityName": "xyz",
"CompanyName": "xyz",
"CreditDays": "12",
"CusotmerID": "45",
"Email": "f@gmail.com",
"GSTNo": "1234",
"IsApproved": "False",
"Lat": "",
"Long": "",
"Mobile": "1234567891",
"Pincode": "",
"Route": "",
"StateID": "1",
"StateName": "xyz",
"UniqueNumber": ""
},
"message": "Data updated successfully",
"status": 200
}

->>>> API SERVICES
List Customerlist = [];

```
Future<List<GetCustomer>> getPostApi() async {
final response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse(
        'xyz'),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Charset": "utf-8",
    },
    body: (jsonEncode({'CustomerID': 1})));

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  // Map<String, dynamic> map = json.decode(response.body);

  Map<String, dynamic> map =
      new Map<String, dynamic>.from(json.decode(response.body));

  List<dynamic> data = map["data"];

  Customerlist.clear();
  for (var i in data) {
    Customerlist.add(GetCustomer.fromJson(i));
  }
  return Customerlist;
} else {
  return Customerlist;
}
```

} -----> ERROR WHEN CALLING THIS SERVICES ERROR('String is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `data` in response is Object type not an Array. No need for `loop`

```
 Map<String, dynamic> map =
      new Map<String, dynamic>.from(json.decode(response.body));

  var data = map["data"];

Customerlist.clear();
Customerlist.add(GetCustomer.fromJson(data));
```